# How to collect values in a variable from DOM (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, odometer

I am trying to get this to work:
https://bk.saskialund.de/step2.php

current issue:
when changing a digit (via click on hexagon), I want to store the selected number as value of a hidden input field next to the digit within the DOM ( for example).

How can I get this done with current html and js setup as visible at given link?

Thanks!
Saskia

EDIT:
I did that, but it didnt work for some reason. 
What I did now, is the following to get it to work:
modified the hidden input from
`<input type="number" hidden id="hex1" name"hex1">` to
`<input type="hidden id="hex1" name"hex1">`

And then I moved the val() line above the return statement like so:

```
$(function() {
    var odometer1, value1; 
    odometer1 = $('#hexin1 .odometer');
    value1 = +odometer1.text();

    return odometer1.on('click', function() {
    if(value1 < 9){
      value1 += 1;
    } else {
        value1 -= 9;
    }
    $('#hex1').val(value1);
      return odometer1.html(value1);

    });
});
```

Comment: You must get the value inside the 'on click' function, else it stays to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put any code so I assume you can do something like this :

```
$('.odometer').on('click', function() {
    var item = $(this);
    var value = item.find('odometer-digit-inner').text();
    value = parseInt(value);
    $('input[name=myinput]').val(value);
});
```

But you better intercept the value directly when you calculate it.

Comment: I did that, but it didnt work for some reason. 
What I did now, is the following to get it to work: